# Rotate image in SDL

Tags: c, linux, sdl

I've got working program that blur an image and I have to make similar function that is rotating image. I wrote algorithm that is inversing 2d array:

```
int old_data[height][width];
int new_data[width][height];

for(i=0; i<width; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<height; j++) {
        new_data[i][j] = old_data[height-1-j][i];
    }
}
```

This is my bluring program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>

void Filter(unsigned char * buf, int width, int height, int size, char bpp, unsigned short pitch)
{
  printf("%d %d %d\n", width, height, (int)bpp);
  unsigned char *tmp = (unsigned char*)malloc(pitch*height);
  memcpy(tmp, buf, pitch*height);
  int pix[9], sum, count;
  int x, y, k, i;
  for(y=0; y<height; ++y)
    for(x=0; x<width; ++x)
    {

      pix[0] = y*pitch + x*bpp; 
      pix[1] = pix[0] - pitch; 
      pix[2] = pix[0] + pitch; 
      pix[3] = pix[1] - bpp; 
      pix[4] = pix[1] + bpp; 
      pix[5] = pix[0] - bpp; 
      pix[6] = pix[0] + bpp; 
      pix[7] = pix[2] - bpp; 
      pix[8] = pix[2] + bpp; 

      for(k=0; k<bpp; ++k)
      {
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        for(i=0; i<9; ++i)
        {
          if(pix[i]>=0 && pix[i]<pitch*height)
          {
            sum += (int) (tmp[ pix[i]+k ]);
            ++count;
          }
        }
        sum /= count;
        buf[ pix[0]+k ] = (unsigned char)sum;
      }
    }
}


SDL_Surface* Load_image(char *file_name)
{
        /* Open the image file */
        SDL_Surface* tmp = IMG_Load(file_name);
        if ( tmp == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load %s: %s\n",
                    file_name, SDL_GetError());
                exit(0);
        }
        return tmp; 
}

void Paint(SDL_Surface* image, SDL_Surface* screen)
{
        SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screen, NULL);
        SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
};





int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Uint32 flags;
    SDL_Surface *screen, *image;
    int depth, done;
    SDL_Event event;

    /* Check command line usage */
    if ( ! argv[1] ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <image_file>, (int) size\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }

    if ( ! argv[2] ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <image_file>, (int) size\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }

    /* Initialize the SDL library */
    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        return(255);
    }

    flags = SDL_SWSURFACE;
    image = Load_image( argv[1] );
    printf( "\n\nImage properts:\n" );
    printf( "BitsPerPixel = %i \n", image->format->BitsPerPixel );
    printf( "BytesPerPixel = %i \n", image->format->BytesPerPixel );
    printf( "width %d ,height %d \n\n", image->w, image->h );       

    SDL_WM_SetCaption(argv[1], "showimage");

    /* Create a display for the image */
    depth = SDL_VideoModeOK(image->w, image->h, 32, flags);
    /* Use the deepest native mode, except that we emulate 32bpp
       for viewing non-indexed images on 8bpp screens */
    if ( depth == 0 ) {
        if ( image->format->BytesPerPixel > 1 ) {
            depth = 32;
        } else {
            depth = 8;
        }
    } else
    if ( (image->format->BytesPerPixel > 1) && (depth == 8) ) {
            depth = 32;
    }
    if(depth == 8)
        flags |= SDL_HWPALETTE;
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(image->w, image->h, depth, flags);
    if ( screen == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't set %dx%dx%d video mode: %s\n",
            image->w, image->h, depth, SDL_GetError());
    }

    /* Set the palette, if one exists */
    if ( image->format->palette ) {
        SDL_SetColors(screen, image->format->palette->colors,
                  0, image->format->palette->ncolors);
    }


        printf("$$$$$$ %u \n", image->pitch);
    /* Display the image */
    Paint(image, screen);

    done = 0;
    int size =atoi( argv[2] );
    printf("Actual size is: %d\n", size);
    while ( ! done ) {
        if ( SDL_PollEvent(&event) ) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_KEYUP:
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
                    case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    case SDLK_TAB:
                    case SDLK_q:
                    done = 1;
                    break;
                    case SDLK_SPACE:
                    case SDLK_f:
                    SDL_LockSurface(image);

                    printf("Start filtering...  ");
                    Filter(image->pixels,image->w,image->h, size, image->format->BytesPerPixel, image->pitch);
                    printf("Done.\n");

                    SDL_UnlockSurface(image);

                    printf("Repainting after filtered...  ");
                    Paint(image, screen);
                    printf("Done.\n");

                    break;
                    case SDLK_r:
                    printf("Reloading image...  ");
                    image = Load_image( argv[1] );
                    Paint(image,screen);
                    printf("Done.\n");
                    break;
                    case SDLK_PAGEDOWN:
                    case SDLK_DOWN:
                    case SDLK_KP_MINUS:
                    size--;
                    if (size==0) size--;
                    printf("Actual size is: %d\n", size);
                        break;
                    case SDLK_PAGEUP:
                    case SDLK_UP:
                    case SDLK_KP_PLUS:
                    size++;
                    if (size==0) size++;
                    printf("Actual size is: %d\n", size);
                    break;      
                   case SDLK_s:
                    printf("Saving surface at nowy.bmp ...");
                    SDL_SaveBMP(image, "nowy.bmp" ); 
                    printf("Done.\n");
                    default:
                    break;
                }
                break;
//              case  SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
//              done = 1;
//              break;
                            case SDL_QUIT:
                done = 1;
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        } else {
            SDL_Delay(10);
        }
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    /* We're done! */
    SDL_Quit();
    return(0);
}
```

Could anyone help me to change Filter function that will rotating an image?

Comment: Rotate by a fixed angle? Any angle? Only 90 degree steps? Other steps? What have you tried? How did it work? How *didn't* it work?

Comment: Rotate by 90 degrees. It's filtering always when I clicking space. It's only about implement this algorithm in this function I don't exactly know how to saves pixels in new image.

Comment: Rotate by 90 degree steps is *very* simple. I suggest you make a dummy image of 5x4 *on paper*, and then draw the same image rotated. Then it's very easy to transfer it to code.

Comment: But I wrote algorithm that is working on table and I just need to implement it in Filter function. I don't know SDL that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: I've got something like this: http://pastebin.com/Ya75GR7V but that doesn't work. My problem is that I don't know to put pixels in right places. I have this working code above, but It's a bit different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SDL, it's just a simple transformation.

Lets consider you have this simple image (where `x?` and `y?` represents the coordinates):

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x0,y0 | x1,y0 | x2,y0 | x3,y0 | x4,y0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x0,y1 | x1,y1 | x2,y1 | x3,y1 | x4,y1 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x0,y2 | x1,y2 | x2,y2 | x3,y2 | x4,y2 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x0,y3 | x1,y3 | x2,y3 | x3,y3 | x4,y3 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

And you want to rotate it 90 degrees to the right. That means that the top-left pixel will be the new top-right, and the bottom-left will be the new top-left. So after it will look like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x0,y3 | x0,y2 | x0,y1 | x0,y0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x1,y3 | x1,y2 | x1,y1 | x1,y0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x2,y3 | x2,y2 | x2,y1 | x2,y0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x3,y3 | x3,y2 | x3,y1 | x3,y0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| x4,y3 | x4,y2 | x4,y1 | x4,y0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

So what you need to do is get the width and height of the original image, and create a destination bitmap with the width and height reversed (so the width becomes the height, and vice verse), otherwise the destination bitmap should be the same as the source bitmap.

Then declare a variable which will contain the destination X coordinate, and initialize it to the max destination X coordinate (in my example above it will be initialized to `3`). Create two nested loops, the outer (for example) going over the X coordinates (from zero to the width of the source bitmap), and the inner doing the same but for the Y coordinates.

In the inner loop you take the source X,Y pixel and place it in the destination on the destination-X,source-X coordinate (note that you use the source X as destination Y), and decrease the destination X coordinate. If the destination X coordinate is zero, then reset it to the max destination coordinate (i.e. `3` in out example).

To rotate by 270 degrees (or, rather, -90 degrees) then it's the same but a little opposite, if you get my drift.

---

To rotate by 180 degrees you can either do two 90-degree rotations, or first mirror vertically followed by a mirror horizontally.

---

Also note that my algorithm above is generic for images of all sizes and dimensions.

---

Pseudo-code for rotating:

```
bitmap create_bitmap(width, height) { ... }

int get_pixel(bitmap, x, y) { ... }

void set_pixel(bitmap, x, y) { ... }

bitmap rotate_image(bitmap source)
{
    bitmap destination;

    source_width  = source.width;
    source_height = source.height;

    /* Switch place of width and height */
    destination = create_bitmap(source_height, source_width);

    for (x = 0; x < source_width; ++x)
    {
        dest_x = source_height - 1;

        for (y = 0; y < source_height; ++y)
        {
            source_pixel = get_pixel(source, x, y);

            set_pixel(destination, dest_x, x);

            dest_x = dest_x - 1;
        }
    }

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I've got working algorithm to rotate array. It's working with integers. My problem is, that I can't implement it in my program. I know that it should be something like this: http://pastebin.com/Ya75GR7V but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3448282 The biggest problem with the function you made is that you use a pointer as a pointer-to-pointer (or array of arrays). That will most likely lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. It's so confusing for me.

Comment: @user3448282 Then sleep on it, and come back with fresh eyes tomorrow. The important part is the two "images", and seeing the pattern between them. If you still haven't figured it out in a day or two I'll write some pseudo-code to help you.

Comment: Could you write this pseudo-code right now? I've been mostly using java so far, that's why I have so much troubles with pointers..